# Create a simple user input dialog box for an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an input dialog box for a spreadsheet where it will add to a list of names in a table and also add a row with specific formulas on the main sheet that refer to the table (there are special formulas on the table too, but those get added when I create a new row.) Here's a pic of the workbook's main page:

[image: The Main worksheet]

The idea here is this: I work for a construction company, we need to be able to track where our manpower and equipment are on a given day. To that end, I've been working on a spreadsheet that automates a lot of the process. The jobs are typed in manually, equipment is selected from a dropdown on a weekly basis (equipment tends to move around less often than employees), employees are selected from a dropdown on a daily basis (with a maximum of 6 employees per jobsite). With manpower the manpower situation being particularly tricky, we have a labor pool on the bottom with every employee's name in it for each day of the week. These names disappear as they are used on a given day by aid of a table and some logic in the table on the back-end. Each column is a direct reference to a specific cell on the table, but I'd rather not have these cells populated with formulas. Ultimately, after figuring out this side of it, I can more or less do the opposite to create a "Remove Employee" button.

[image: The Employee Table]

Here's the employee table in a separate sheet, the first column is where the names need to be input. Then you have two columns for each day. a column with either a one or a zero that indicates the name's presence on a given day, and a column that checks if the column on the left is equal to zero, returns the first column (where the name is input) and "" if it is not equal to zero. The right column is where the labor pool of the main sheet are pulled from.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm trying to foolproof the sheet so any member of management can use it without having to understand how it works in order to use it properly. I'm pretty familiar with Bash and Python, I dabble in those two languages on my own machine at home (I know you're asking, a construction dude messing around with programming? I accidentally deleted my entire Windows installation years ago, didn't have much money to get a fresh install, so I settled for Linux Mint and fell in love with the FOSS world). The long and short of it is, I could probably record a macro in excel that would function the way I want it to, but those never really work the way you want them to. Besides, I'd be short-changing myself on a learning opportunity.

I've tried getting the answer to this from other sites, but I can't find a place where someone is trying to do something similar. Maybe I'm just not finding it. I've tried creating the user form in the VBA code editor, and I can make a nice looking form, but after that, I try to edit code, and I just don't even know where to start. Additionally, I'm looking for a good place to learn VBA.

Comment: Coding has a lot to do with figuring out the logic you need for what you're trying to achieve. From there, it's a matter of getting it working through trial and error. Usually people don't get into the "full-blown" project like what you're trying here but here are a few pointers: 1) If you're going for a visual representation of who/how many employees are left while using vba, you don't need a secundary table for it. VBA can handle removing/resetting that range. 2) If your managers are going to do one project at a time, the Userform could have a listbox filled with the remaining employees.

Comment: The filling of a listbox [has been asked/answered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+fill+listbox+with+range) a bunch of times. [Transferring userform data to worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+userform+to+worksheet) as well and if you're stuck on something, you can ask a more focused question then.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your code.

Comment: Welcome LizardPope1101! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour